# Why is my SwiftUI custom drawer overlay animation jittery when I'm not scrolling in a ScrollView?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation, swiftui-transition

Running into some weird behavior with the SwiftUI rendering engine and I'm wondering if anyone can shed some light into it.

For context, I'm creating a custom Drawer View using an overlay. The specific animation in question is the drawer view moving up from the bottom of the screen using `.transition(.move(.bottom))`

For some reason, the drawer animation coming up is a bit jittery, unless a scrollview is moving while I tap the drawer open button.

Testing on a real device, 2 scenarios to test

1. tap open drawer with scrollview being static
2. swipe horizontal scroll view and tap open drawer while it still is moving

And here is a minimally reproduced example:

`Main Base View`

```
struct BaseView: View {
    @State private var isDrawerActive:Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Button {
                isDrawerActive.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Open Drawer")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            .padding(.top)
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<10) { _ in
                        Text("scroll for buttery smooth animations")
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 100)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .overlay(
            DrawerContainerView(isActive: $isDrawerActive)
        )
    }
}
```

`Drawer Container View`

```
struct DrawerContainerView: View {
    @Binding var isActive:Bool
    @State private var verticalOffset:CGFloat = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            Color.black
                .opacity(0.1)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.interactiveSpring(response: 0.4, dampingFraction: 0.8, blendDuration: 0)) {
                        verticalOffset += 100
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.01) {
                            isActive = false
                        }
                    }
                }
                .opacity(isActive ? 1.0 : 0.0)
            if isActive {
                DrawerView()
                    .offset(y: verticalOffset)
                    .zIndex(2)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
        }
        .animation(.interactiveSpring(response: 0.4, dampingFraction: 0.8, blendDuration: 0), value: isActive)
        .onChange(of: isActive) { b in
            verticalOffset = .zero
        }
    }
}
```

`Drawer View`

```
struct DrawerView: View {
    let cells:[String] = ["Edit Settings", "Edit Bio", "Settings", "Close Friend", "Emojis", "Status Settings", "Account"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                .frame(width: 32, height: 3.5)
                .foregroundColor(.gray.opacity(0.3))
                .padding(.top, 15)
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
            
            ForEach(cells, id: \.self) { text in
                Text(text)
                    .font(.headline.weight(.semibold))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding()
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18, style: .continuous).foregroundColor(.gray.opacity(0.1)))
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .shadow(color: .gray.opacity(0.5), radius: 8)
                .padding(.bottom, -20)
        )
        .padding(.bottom)
        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
    }
}
```

Would be amazing if anyone could shed light on this. Thanks